# Как в codeception последовательно сделать клик по нескольким элементам с зажатым 'shift'

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, codeception

Добрый день.
требуется выделить несколько блоков кликнув по каждому, но при этом должен быть зажат shift, т.е сначала один элемент (шифт зажат потом второй, и третий). Аналогично мы выбираем например нужные папки в файл менеджере. можно это сделать используя codeception или нативные методы ?

Comment: могу на `c#` привести пример....

Comment: да, пожалуйста, попробую разобраться. Codeception вроде может вызывать нативные методы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам себе отвечу,

```
$I->executeInSelenium(function (\Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver $webdriver) {
    $el = $webdriver->findElement(\Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::cssSelector('#testTarget'));
    $webdriver->action()->sendKeys(null, WebDriverKeys::SHIFT)->click($el)->perform();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте нажать шифт так:

```
$I->pressKey('#input',WebDriverKeys::LEFT_SHIFT);
```

Comment: К сожалению так не работает, так как, 
надо нажать shift и потом нажать клик не отпуская shift, по отдельности работает конечно, экспериментировал тут:
http://www.spookandpuff.com/examples/clickSimulation.html